# Jmeter sampler 'v1/pages/...' produces 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space' error

Tags: jmeter, heap-memory

When I run JMeter test with 100 Threads on Azure pipeline I get 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space' error. I tried to increase HEAP:

```
set HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx2048m
```

and even more but no effect.

I noticed that sampler 'v1/pages/...'produces this heap error. I wasn't able to find any information about this kind of sampler, so I have two questions:

1. Is it worthy to keep this sampler? Maybe it's not so important and removing it would fix my problem.
   This 'v1/pages' comes from '//content-autofill.googleapis.com/v1/pages/'and it looks like nothing important
2. Do you know any other methods to handle this HEAP error? Everyone is saying about increasing values in this Xmx, but it's not working for me.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This `v1/pages` is just a label, don't waste your time by searching for it, sampler labels may be absolutely different:

   [image]

   if you open [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) you should see the URL of the request and once you figure this out you will be able to make the decision whether to keep it or not.

   One of possible reasons is that particular this request returns large response which doesn't fit into memory, if this is the case and you're not too interested in the response - you can tick "Save response as MD5 hash" instead:

   [image]
2. There are 2 ways of fixing "Java heap space" error:

   - Reduce heap usage, i.e. see this hint with MD5 sum or consider going for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
   - Increase heap size. For example 2 gigabytes may be not enough, try allocating more heap if you have enough RAM. Also if your pipeline is running on Linux you need to slightly amend your command to look like: `HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx2048m && export HEAP && ./jmeter -n -t test.jmx ......`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I checked this v1/pages and it comes from '//content-autofill.googleapis.com/v1/pages/'. Do you think this is important and keep this sampler?

Comment: I don't think so, if you're not a Google engineer testing its autofill funcitonality you should be excluding these requests to `googleapis.com` (and any other external domains) from your load testing scope, it includes any 3rd-party images, banners, etc. More information: [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test). However this OOM error is something you should address as well because it indicates certain problems with your JMeter setup